# Support Vectors confusion

Tags: machine-learning, svm, optimization, linear-model

I am reading the chapter 9 about support vector machines from *An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R by Gareth James et al.*

In pages 345-349 they talk about soft margins etc.

They claim that in this image with soft margin, there are 8 support vectors. I see 9.

[image]

According to the book:

*Observations that lie directly on the margin, or on the wrong side of the margin for their class, are known as support vectors.*

I am even more confused after this. Does it mean that if they are on the wrong side of the hyperplane they count as support vectors as long as they are placed into the margins?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are on the "wrong side" of the margin, you count as a support vector.

This means that the blue dot on the right **is** a support vector as well as all points lying between both margins.

The fact that you see 9 support vectors might be due to the fact that one point seems o be on the margin but actually is slightly on the good side of it. I can see no other explanation.